# Target "release" does not exist in the project "core"

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to build my Android project in release mode using Ant but it is failing with the following error:

"Target "release" does not exist in the project "core"".

Building for Debug is working fine. It is also worth mentioning the following:

- I do not have a project called "core" anywhere in the mix.
- That the failure is on one of the dependent projects "DevsmartAndroid_horizontal_list_view"
- I can build the "DevsmartAndroid_horizontal_list_view" on its own by calling it's  build.xml directly and issuing ant release.

I am finding it difficult to narrow down the source of this error. Any ideas on how to solve?

Many Thanks.

Comment: ant -verbose -debug <target> will write a ton of logs but generally will help get you closer to where the failure point is.

Comment: I eventually remembered to use -verbose which indicated the problem very quickly. Thanks! If you answer this question I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Ant with command line args `-verbose` and `-debug` - that may help provide a clue.